# How to use Bean Validation in a Helidon App?

Tags: helidon

I'm trying to create a simple Rest Resource using Helidon-MP but for some reason it doesn't work when I add the bean validation annotations on my method.

```
@POST
public Response generatePlan(@Valid @ValidPlan JsonObject payload) {
   // some logic here
}
```

Is this the expected behavior? Or Should I add some dependency or configuration?

I tried to find something on the documentation, but I couldn't.

Thanks

---

I ended up doing as @LairdNelson answered and added the following dependencies in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
     <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
     <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>jakarta.el</groupId>
     <artifactId>jakarta.el-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
     <artifactId>jakarta.el</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bean validation is not part of the MicroProfile set of specifications, so by default it is not part of Helidon MP, which is a MicroProfile implementation.

You may of course add an implementation of Bean Validation on your compile or runtime classpath provided it is a CDI portable extension (which is how you add arbitrary capabilities to any MicroProfile-compliant implementation).  One such portable extension is the [Hibernate Validator-backed one](https://search.maven.org/classic/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.hibernate.validator%22%20AND%20a%3A%22hibernate-validator-cdi%22).  There may certainly be others.

Comment: Thanks @LairdNelson, I ended up doing exactly what you say in this answer. I was just wondering if there were some helidon dependency that adds this for me.

Comment: No; there's not really any functionality to add here above and beyond a bean validation implementation—CDI does the hard work of integration for you.